# How to display percent ( %) symbol in Y axis value in crystal report , line chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, graph, crystal-reports

I want to add percentage symbol on Y axis value in crystal report? I tried using chart expert --> Data axis --> number format as percentage but it is not working.  How to achieve this.

[image]

I want to graph look like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 01

[image]

### Step 02

[image]

### Step 03

[image]

### Step 04

[image]

### Step 05

[image]

### Step 06

[image]

### Step 07

[image]

### Step 08

[image]

### Step 09

[image]

### Step 10

[image]

### Step 11

[image]

### Step 12

[image]

### Step 13

[image]

### Step 14

[image]

### Step 15

[image]

### Step 16

[image]

Comment: Can't see the formula clearly. And can't we give the auto arrange to axis because my data also has negative values?

Comment: @Manusha {table.filed1}/sum({{table.filed1}})